# Customized sort in the order mentioned {2,3....9,A,B,C,D,1,E,F,0}

Tags: c, sorting

I am currently implementing a logic to sort the alphanumerical numbers in the order as mentioned {2,3....9,A,B,C,D,1,E,F,0}. Is there a easy and a possible way to do this? I prefer only C programming.

The request is regarding the sort of the 1st nibble in the PI code of FM RDS stations. As Germany is the only country which supports 2 PI codes(D & 1), the order is maintained in this manner.

Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: The community will respond better if you show that you attempted the solution. I will update my answer if you do this to provide you a more thorough answer.

Comment: By "alphanumerical numbers", what do you mean? What types are you trying to sort?

Comment: @KyleStrand : As I updated my description I'm sorting the 1st nibble in the PI code of FM RDS stations. It is ranging from 0 to F but the desired output of the sort order is {2,3....9,A,B,C,D,1,E,F,0}

Comment: @GregSchmit: I'm really sorry to say that I'm very poor in writing source code and so would like to get some hints/ideas/inputs maybe to try out on my own. So Please support.

Comment: @Siva This is not a code writing service, so I might do one if my caffeine intake requires some engine revving for me to sleep, but you should really be putting in effort yourself. Keep in mind that you're likely to get downvoted for being lazy.

Comment: @GregSchmit: Sure I'm continuously working to learn more by writing my own. Thanks for your concern. But your ideas will be more helpful and so I posted a post here.

Comment: @Siva I added an implementation.

Comment: @GregSchmit: Thank you very much for your support. But I am expecting something else bro. It is not about sorting a single string "char string[33] = "00FFEE11DDCCBBAA9988776655443322"", it is about sorting a list of characters like char string1[1] = "D", char string2[1] = "1" and so on...

Comment: That is **not** a list of characters. In C, a list of characters is called a character array. Either way, you can easily modify my code to do that. Just take your "list", compare each item using the compare method, and re-order them.

Comment: If you really want to do that, you can also combine them into a string, sort them, and then redistribute the elements.

Comment: I am not going to write more code for you. I gave you plenty to get you started (a full working implementation of a sorting algorithms that sorts based on your specifications).

Comment: Siva, it sounds like you don't really consider yourself much of a programmer yet and don't know much about C. Out of curiosity, have you considered implementing whatever it is you need in an easier language, such as Python or Ruby?

Answer (score 1):

You should write a function (e.g., `int custom_compare(const void *p1, const void *p2);` that defines this sorting order. That method will return `1` if `p1` comes after `p2`, `0` if they are 'equal', and `-1` if `p1` comes before `p2`.

Then, write your sorting method and call your ordering function instead of comparing using operators. That is, instead of `if (a < b)`, use `if (custom_compare(&b, &a))`.

Also, I created that function prototype above (specifically using pointers as the parameters) because it would work with the `qsort` library, which is a quicksort implementation that accepts a custom comparison function.

## An Implementation

I decided to quickly do a implementation of what I suggested and a small test example.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int custom_compare(const void *p1, const void *p2) {
    char *param1 = (char*)p1;
    char *param2 = (char*)p2;
    int loc1 = 0;
    int loc2 = 0;
    char order[17] = "23456789ABCD1EF0";
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<17; i++) {
        if (*param1 == order[i]) { loc1 = i; }
        if (*param2 == order[i]) { loc2 = i; }
    }
    if (loc2 < loc1) {
        return 1;
    } else if (loc1 < loc2) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

void bubble_sort_string(char *string) {
    if (!string || !string[0] || !string[1]) { return; }
    int i;
    int tail = 0;
    char tmp;
    while (string[tail]) { tail++; }
    while (tail) {
        i = 1;
        while (i <= tail) {
            if (custom_compare(&string[i-1], &string[i]) > 0) {
                // swap
                tmp = string[i];
                string[i] = string[i-1];
                string[i-1] = tmp;
            }
            i++;
        }
        tail--;
    }
}

int main() {
    char string[33] = "00FFEE11DDCCBBAA9988776655443322";
    printf("old string: %s\n", string);
    bubble_sort_string(string);
    printf("new_string: %s\n", string);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
$ ./csort 
old string: 00FFEE11DDCCBBAA9988776655443322
new_string: 2233445566778899AABBCCDD11EEFF00
$
```